# Trying to read string-based binary (?) code into something like WKT to be read by a spatial database

Tags: well-known-text, binary

I've recently received some parcel data that has "shape" columns which are strings by default and look something like this:

```
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
```

What kind of code is this and is there any way to convert it back into something readable by qgis or postgis?

Comment: Interesting, but that doesn't look like any of the binary formats I'm familiar with. It isn't WKB (which has to start with 00 or 01 to indicate byte order), nor is it the post-gis EWKB (again, has start with a byte order indication). It does look like it starts with some kind of bounding box, but it might help if you can confirm that is all of the hex blob, and to post some more samples. Failing that, you'd need to ask the originator.

Comment: The "0F" bothered me too; I tried running it through a shapefile binary parser, but it reported a coordinate system extent error.  I think you need to ask the provider  what 1) format, 2) topology class (line vs poly), 3) extent, and 4) coordinate system to expect.  It might be useful to confirm that the binary data is in Intel byte order (vice Motorola).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a hex dump of Well-Known Binary (WKB).  If you convert it to binary (2 characters per byte) and from there into a BLOB, you can likely convert it to PG_GEOMETRY (though it would probably help to know what the source coordinate system was).